# Can we trigger background script of chrome extension at particular time (e.g. every day at 7 P.M.) from our server?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, server, triggers, background

I know there is chrome api creatalarm but will it work with background script?

Comment: The alarms API works in a background script so it's unclear what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Yes, you can trigger your background script using the `alarms` API to run at a particular time. 

If you need data from your server, I would recommend using the built-in `alarms` API to fetch from the server, rather then attempting to have the server trigger a function in the extension.

Comment: I want to make my extension active at particular time, so I was thinking to trigger alarm in background script. but if there is another approach to invoke content script through background at particular time Please suggest. Thanks in advance :S

Comment: I've been following official doc for that https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#security-considerations
but it is giving me an error as receiving end is not specified.